Some tomcat metrics are not visible using Prometheus with Spring Boot 3.x

Spring Boot Version: 3.3.2
Dependency

io.micrometer:micrometer-core (latest)
io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus (latest)



Some tomcat metrics are not visible.
Metrics that are output.

tomcat.sessions.active.current
tomcat.sessions.active.max
tomcat.sessions.alive.max
tomcat.sessions.created
tomcat.sessions.expired
tomcat.sessions.rejected

Metrics that are not printed

tomcat.global.request.max
tomcat.global.request.count
tomcat.threads.config.max
tomcat.threads.current
tomcat.threads.busy
tomcat.connections.max
tomcat.connections.current
tomcat.connections.keepalive.current
tomcat.servlet.request.max
tomcat.servlet.request.count
tomcat.servlet.request.total-time

This is application.yaml
spring:
  application:
    name: myapplicationname
management:
  server:
    port: 9123
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
      base-path: /actuator
  endpoint:
    metrics:
      enabled: true
    health:
      enabled: true
      probes:
        enabled: true
  health:
    livenessstate:
      enabled: true
    readinessstate:
      enabled: true
  metrics:
    enable:
      tomcat: true
    tags:
      application: 'myapplicationnameee'
    distribution:
      percentiles-histogram:
        tomcat:
          request: true
        reactor:
          onNext:
            delay: true
    export:
      prometheus:
        pushgateway:
          enabled: true
          push-rate: 1s
server:
  port: 98765
  shutdown: graceful


Welcome to SO. Please provide a minimal reproducible example to try to reproduce the error and debug it. You also haven't asked a question. Please update your post with an actual question, expected behaviour, observed behaviour, and what you've tried to fix it.

These metrics are read from Tomcat MBeans. Use the server.tomcat.mbeanregistry.enabled=true property

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
